# Compare dataset with another dataset for multiple Columns/Values SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

This is the image reference. Let me explain the scenario.

[image]

There are two datasets A and B as you can see, dataset B has actual tests values and dataset A has target values (more like ranges). code compares each test (BLK ...) value to the target test (BLK ...) value, code is shown below

```
=IIF(Len(Lookup("UR_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target")) <= 0,
(
IIF(Fields!BLK.Value > Lookup("UW_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Yellow",
        IIF(Fields!BLK.Value < Lookup("LW_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Yellow","Green"))
),

(
IIF(Fields!BLK.Value > Lookup("UR_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Red",
    IIF(Fields!BLK.Value > Lookup("UW_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Yellow",
        IIF(Fields!BLK.Value < Lookup("LR_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Red",
            IIF(Fields!BLK.Value < Lookup("LW_Limit",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),"Yellow","Green"))))
))
```

Now the problem I face is, that I cant compare each products test (from B) values to that specific products target values in dataset A. What ends up happening is that each test in B is compared by last target product values in dataset A.

Comment: You problem is different products is being compared, you want `905200` product in Daily Test Data be compared with `905200` product in Target Values, right?

Comment: is this possible????

Comment: I think there is way to achieve this by creating a calculated field and concatenate the Product and the Limit. I don't understand the limits for BLK in the Test Target Values, note the UW_limit is 141 and the UR_Limit is 110, isn't it supposed to be smaller?.

Comment: yes, there is some data wrongly entered. but you have the concept though. i tried concatenating product and limits, but not able to use it in lookup because you can only look for one string in lookup and there is no limit column in test data table (B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating product and limit fields it is possible as mentioned in comments. The lookup function can use any string you pass to search for a value. Note the following example:

```
Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "UR_Limit",...,"TestTargetDataSet")
```

It will look for `905200-UR_Limit` and return the `BLK` value for upper limit from the Test Target Values. Of course you have to create a calculated field in the TestTarget Dataset and set it as the concatenation of product and limit fields.

I've recreated your scenario using the tables you provided. First I created the calculated field named `PRLimit` in the Test Target dataset and set it to this expression:

```
=Fields!Product.Value & "-" & Fields!Limits.Value
```

As you mentioned in comments you have multiple columns, you have to use a different expression for each column:

```
=Switch(
Fields!BLK.Value >
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "UW_Limit",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Red",
Fields!BLK.Value >
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Yellow",
Fields!BLK.Value =
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Green",
Fields!BLK.Value <
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "LW_Limit",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Red",
Fields!BLK.Value <
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Yellow"
)
```

---

```
=Switch(
Fields!BW.Value >
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "UW_Limit",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BW.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Red",
Fields!BW.Value >
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BW.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Yellow",
Fields!BW.Value =
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BW.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Green",
Fields!BW.Value <
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "LW_Limit",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BW.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Red",
Fields!BW.Value <
  Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "Target",Fields!PRLimit.Value,Fields!BW.Value,"DataSet9"),
  "Yellow"
)
```

The above expressions are used to get the right color for BLK and BW columns respectively. The logic used is:

- IF BLK value is greater than the `UW` BLK value: Color in Red
- ELSE IF BLK value is greater than the `Target` value: Color in Yellow
- ELSE IF BLK value is equal to `Target` value: Color in Green
- ELSE IF BLK value is less than the `LW` BLK value: Color in Red
- ELSE IF BLK value is less than the `Target` BLK value: Color in Yellow

This is the final result with the data provided in your question:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it works thanks, but there is still a little issue around. while using these lookup there is one issue of repetitive rows. for example
`905200 - UR_Limit ..........................
 905200 - UW_Limit .........................
 905200 - Target ..............................
 905200 - LW_Limit ..........................
 905200 - LW_Limit .......................... this row gets repoeated
`

Comment: If they are repeated on the target table it will cause color be the same for every row of 905200 product in the test table. I don't understand what your problem is

Comment: think of target table only, and then i apply the above color logic in the font color section, if i use Switch(....UR_Limit) only it disappears from the table, if i use switch(...UW_Limit ) i gets repeated. 
let me know if you still dont get it

Comment: `=IIF(Fields!BLK.Value = Lookup(Fields!Product.Value & "-" & "2 - Upper Warning", Fields!Product_Desc.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Test_Target"),"Tan","Green")`

2 - Upper Warning row disappears from the table, replaces by any row on the top